# daterangerpicker with singledatepicker issues

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker, daterangepicker

I trying to use daterangepicker as datetime picker, Which is working fine with following code.

```
  function openDatePicker(obj, extras)     {
     obj.daterangepicker({
            showDropdowns: true,
            autoUpdateInput: false,
            startDate: extras.date,
            singleDatePicker: true,
            timePicker: true,
            timePicker24Hour: true,
            applyClass: 'bg-slate-600',
            cancelClass: 'btn-default',
            locale: {
                format: 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm'
            }
        });
  }
```

But I have some issues.

1) First apply/cancel button not showing at all.

2) Second I need to set date after daterangepicker is applied example on some event. Following code I found not working.

```
      obj.daterangepicker({
            //showWeekNumbers: true,
            showDropdowns: true,
            autoUpdateInput: false,
            startDate: extras.date,
            singleDatePicker: true,
            timePicker: true,
            timePicker24Hour: true,
            applyClass: 'bg-slate-600',
            cancelClass: 'btn-default',
            locale: {
                format: 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm'
            },
            //autoApply: false
        },
        function(chosen_date) {
            obj.val(chosen_date.format('MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm'));
        });
```

Third I need to set one date field after choosing date from another field, Let say plus 5 day from chosen date. I tried event 'apply.daterangepicker' on first date which not executing when I close picker after click outside, Also i tried hide.daterangepicker which is executing but give empty date value.

```
$('#SurgeryDate').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {                                         
    $('#DueDate').data( 'daterangepicker' ).setStartDate(picker.startDate.add(5,'d').endOf('day'));
});

$('#SurgeryDate').on('hide.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
    $('#DueDate').data( 'daterangepicker' ).setStartDate(picker.startDate.add(5,'d').endOf('day'));
});
```

I am using version 2.1.23